# If $f$ is one-to-one, then $f^{-1}:N \to M$ is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, continuity

> Let $f: M \to N$ be continuous and onto, and let $M$ be compact. Prove
> that $A$ is closed in $N$ if and only if $f^{-1}(A)$ is closed in $M$.
> Prove that if $f$ is also one-to-one, then $f^{-1}:N \to M$ is
> continuous.

Just want to confirm that $(b)$ is right.

(a) ($\Leftarrow$) We prove the contrapositive: if $A$ is open in $N$, then $f^{-1}(A)$ is open in $M$. This is the definition of continuity, so we're done. $(\Rightarrow)$ Suppose $A$ is closed in $N$ $\Longleftrightarrow$ $A^c$ is open in $N$. By the proof in the $(\Leftarrow)$ direction, we know that $f^{-1}(A^c)$ is open in $M$. Because $f^{-1}(A^c) = M \setminus f^{-1}(A)$, we know that $f^{-1}(A)$ is closed in $M$.

(b) Suppose $f$ is also one-to-one. To show $f^{-1}$ is continuous, we want to show that for any open set $B$ in $M$, $(f^{-1})^{-1}(B) = f(B)$ is an open set in $N$. Let's prove the contrapositive, so suppose $f(B)$ is a closed set in $N$ $\Longleftrightarrow$ $f^{-1}(f(B)) = B$ is closed in $M$

Comment: You haven't used the compactness of $M$. The key facts you need are that continuous images of compact sets are compact and that closed subsets of compact sets are compact.

Comment: @RobArthan Why/where in my proofs do I need that? Where do my proofs fall apart without using those assumptionms

Comment: Take$M = N = \Bbb{R}$,  $f = \exp: \Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}$ and $A = (0, \infty)$. Then $A$ is not closed in $N$ but $f^{-1}(A)$ is closed in $M$. In part (a)($\Leftarrow$) your notion of contrapositive isn't right.

Comment: @RobArthan Just to confirm, the $(\Rightarrow)$ direction in part(a) is correct?

Comment: Not quite: you need to replace the appeal to the $(\Leftarrow)$ direction by an appeal to the continuity of $f$.

Answer (score 2):

As Rob Arthan points out in the comments, the $(\impliedby)$ direction in (a) is incorrect. The statement that requires showing is

> If $f^{-1}(A)$ is closed in $M$, then $A$ is closed in $N$.

However, you try to show

> If $A$ is open in $N$, then $f^{-1}(A)$ is open in $M$.

Note that the statement you have shown is equivalent to the $(\implies$) direction, which is

> If $A$ is closed in $N$, then $f^{-1}(A)$ is closed in $M$,

where the equivalence follows from the fact that openness implies the closeness of the complement, and vice versa. This is why you were able to invoke the proof in one direction to show the other.

Coincidentally, the reasoning for your proof is correct: if $f$ is continuous and the image of $f$ is closed, then its pre-image is also closed, which proves $(\impliedby)$. For $(\implies)$, note that $A = f(f^{-1}(A))$, i.e., $A$ is the image of $f^{-1}(A)$. Since $A$ is closed and $f$ is continuous, it follows from $(\impliedby)$ that $f^{-1}(A)$ is closed, as desired.

---

For (b), we need to use the compactness of $M$. Following the beginning of your proof, it suffices to show that for any open set $B \subset M$, $(f^{-1})^{-1}(B) = f(B) \subset N$ is open. Observe that $B^\complement$ is a closed subset in a compact set $M$, and thus $B^\complement$ is compact. Therefore, $f(B^\complement)$ is also compact, and in particular, closed. Then by the bijectivity of $f$, $f(B^\complement)^\complement = f(B)$ is open, as desired.

Comment: I want to prove: "If $f^{-1}(A)$ is closed in $M$, then $A$ is closed in $N$." I do this by proving the contrapositive: "If $A$ is open in $N$, then $f^{-1}(A)$ is open in $M$." How does this not work?

Comment: I don't see how "If $A$ is open in $N$, then $f^{-1}(A)$ is open in $M$" is equivalent to "If $A$ is closed in $N$, then $f^{-1}(A)$ is closed in $M$"

Comment: I'm also confused by your $(\Leftarrow)$ proof in part (a). You just restate the thing we want to prove